# pointer to string in Array

Tags: swift

During my program execution, I have to load a large array of `MyStruct`

```
// Struct definition
struct MyStruct
{
   var someString: String = ""
}

// Array definition    
var ar = Array<MyStruct>()
```

The issue is, having all these someString take a large amount of memory and could easily be shaved down because they all have common (large) prefixes. These prefix do vary.

So, I would like to have

```
struct MyStruct
{
   var someString: String = ""
   var someString: pointer to a shared string prefix
}
```

My questions are:

How do I tell swift not to assign and copy the string, but rather a pointer to the string.
How do I obtain the pointer to said strings. Currently, I obtain the prefix using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`.

Also, For the strings to be retained somewhere, I plan to put all the prefixes in an array.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `static` variable to achieve that.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    static var prefix: String = "prefix"
    var someString: String = ""
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But If I do that, all struct will share the exact same radical ? However, radicals do vary. Many have the radical X, others have Y, etc...